# gradle call a method at the end of the compilation

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, plugins, android-gradle-plugin

Assume I have a function say encode written in a java file.
taking this is what android studio does,
Compiling java files-> creates class files -> builds the apk with the class files.

Now I want the function to be called right after the class files are created and before the class files get converted to apk.

I work on macOS terminal for gradle , and I created the build.gradle file too.

the build.gradle file is below

```
    apply plugin : "java"
    apply plugin : "application"
    mainClassName = "com.YYYY.XXXX.Main"

    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies{
        compile "asm:asm:3.3.1"
        compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
        compile "org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.3"
        compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7"
        compile "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])

    }

    sourceSets{
        main.java.srcDir "src/main"
    }
    jar{
        from configurations.compile.collect {zipTree it}
        manifest.attributes "Main-Class":"com.YYYY.XXXX.Main"
    }
    task run(type: Exec,dependsOn: jar,overwrite: true){
        executable 'java'
        args '-jar',"$jar.archivePath",'/Users/XXXX/Desktop/','/Users/XXXX/Downloads/cloud/'
        doLast{
            println "Successfully done the obfuscation"
        }
    }
```

Here the class Main is used and is made to run.
How can I achieve the above goal?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the finalizedBy() method from Task:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:finalizedBy(java.lang.Object[])

This should do what you need:

```
compileJava.finalizedBy "run"
```

BTW, there is a more specialized JavaExec task for executing java applications:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: Where to add them? I don't find compileJava as a task under gradle tasks

Comment: compileJava is a task you get from the java plugin, so as long as you have applied the java plugin (apply plugin: "java") then just put that anywhere in the top-level of your build.gradle (i.e. it shouldn't be nested anywhere)

Comment: please help me with this one..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871078/run-grade-tasks-inside-a-task-without-dependson