# Run grade tasks inside a task without dependsOn

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

Assume that I have set of tasks executed from the cmd line and it works:

```
gradle processReleaseManifest compileReleaseSources run assembleRelease
```

Here run is the task which I Defined.

So My requirement is that I need to create a task which executes the above mentioned 4 tasks,
like say new task abc, runs the above mentioned tasks in the same order,

I know I cannot use dependsOn in this case because,processReleaseManifest compileReleaseSource when used in the build gradle it shows,

Could not get unknown property `'assembleRelease'` for project `':app'` of type `org.gradle.api.Project`.

So what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can, as @lu.koerfer's answer indicates use strings in the dependsOn list to refer to tasks that are defined further down in the build file.

In other words, this works:

```
task foo {}
task bar(dependsOn: [foo]) {}
```

and this also works:

```
task bar(dependsOn: ['foo']) {}
task foo {}
```

Now as for getting the tasks to run in the order you want things are not quite as straight forward. The `dependsOn` property only tells the task which tasks need to run before the task itself runs. It does *not* tell gradle to run the tasks in the order defined in the `dependsOn` clause.

An example:

```
task one {}
task two {} 
task three {} 
task run(dependsOn: [one, two, three]) {}
```

results in the following output when run:

```
~> gradle run
:one UP-TO-DATE
:three UP-TO-DATE
:two UP-TO-DATE
:run UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

...note the fact that we are not running in the order `one`, `two`, `three`, `run`.

In other words, the command line invocation forces the tasks to run in the order defined whereas the `dependsOn` is a set and has no ordering.

There are a few ways you can get the tasks to run in the order you want. One is to define dependencies on the tasks (this is probably the common path):

```
task one {}
task two(dependsOn: ['one']) {} 
task three(dependsOn: ['two']) {} 
task run(dependsOn: [one, two, three]) {}
```

which results in:

```
~> gradle run
:one UP-TO-DATE
:two UP-TO-DATE
:three UP-TO-DATE
:run UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

another is to use the [task ordering constructs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) added in later versions of gradle.

Also, if you need to add a task dependency to a task which was defined somewhere earlier in the file, you can do so via:

```
task foo {}
someTaskDefinedFurtherUp.dependsOn 'foo'
```

which adds the task `foo` to the dependencies of `someTaskDefinedFurtherUp`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the task names as strings to the `dependsOn` method, because at the time you call it, the task objects haven't been created yet. However, if you pass strings, the task names will be evaluated later:

```
task abc {
    dependsOn 'processReleaseManifest', 'compileReleaseSources', 'run', 'assembleRelease'
}
```

Comment: See I have,
processReleaseManifest compileReleaseSources run assembleRelease 
the 4 tasks to be run,
So if I do ur step it does only assembleRelease.
I can't make assembleRelease to depend on something, it pops the error which I have mentioned in the question

Comment: Then you should be able to add all of these tasks to the task dependencies of another task via `dependsOn`.

Comment: how can I do that? Can you send a code snippet that I can understand

Comment: Its not running in order , so produces wrong results

Comment: Is there any way like,
     task run(type:JavaExec){
                  executable  'java'
                  main="-jar"
                  args "LogObfuscator.jar",'/release/com','s/cloud/'
                  doLast{
                      println "successful"

                  }
            }

Here we call the java right similarly can be make executable for gradle

Comment: Here we see a jar file right, we can't access it as such, instead we have to give the absolute path in order to access it, suppose we run it in another in another system it will fail , as their absolute path n mine will differ, so, what can be done to get the absolute path of the project , assume the jar is in the libs Dir

Answer (score 0):

As it may be possible but very complicated to specify the task dependencies and ordering via `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter` / `shouldRunAfter`, I'll propose another possible solution:

You can invoke Gradle from Gradle and specify the tasks in same way you would via command line:

```
task abc(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['processReleaseManifest', 'compileReleaseSources', 'run', 'assembleRelease']
}
```

This will call Gradle again from the current build and execute the tasks in the specified order.

Comment: Yea this clears it !
Before closing the thread I need few more answers,
Main concept is run process changes the contents in the class files.
so when I run this abc I get the modified apk.
So rather than doing gradle abc explicitly, How can I insert it in the lifecycle of gradle, this must impact the apk the android studio is building and launch the apk based on the modifed class files

Comment: I would argue that this is very much against the intent of the gradle build system. Yes it works but the question is if you really want to do this. The decision to make `dependsOn` unordered has been [discussed at length in the gradle jira and forums](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-427) and it was left unordered on purpose.

Comment: Do you mean my answer or his additional question? I would agree on both, but it seems like he does not want to search a suitable solution on its own with the tips we gave him (`dependsOn` with strings, task ordering with `mustRunAfter` / `shouldRunAfter`).

Comment: ok I saw the extra comments and I agree. If you really can't use the tools gradle gives you for this problem, then this is at least a solution that works.